# Autofac with Web API: inject dependencies from HttpRequestMessage?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, autofac

I have a need to inject certain values from the HttpRequestMessage (mostly revolving around identity) into some of my objects.

As I understand it, using HttpSession.Current is not recommended in the Web Api framework.  How do I access the HttpRequestMessage for user's Identity and other attributes such as user's IP address, UserAgent, etc. during binding of my dependencies in Autofac?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `builder.RegisterHttpRequestMessage()` while you're building your dependency container. After that, anything that takes an `HttpRequestMessage` as a dependency will get the current message.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the accepted answer of @Travis Illig, the full call should be something like this:

```
builder.RegisterHttpRequestMessage(System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
```